# Need to increase buffer for IPC message queue in OpenWRT

Tags: c, linux, openwrt, sysv-ipc

I'm just learning how to use message queues, and I am having a little difficulty with them.  I am using two completely separate applications to do the testing -- one is the "sender", and the other is the "receiver".

When I run the sender, it sends 15 strings to the pipe, but then afterward fails with a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error.  I just need to consume the messages on the receiver side, but why only 15 messages?  I might be sending lots of messages, so I'd like to increase this to a much larger number, like 1000 or so.

I tried to set the message queue size to 32767, so I was expecting 31 at least, but apparently `msg_qbytes` is not related to the number of messages that can be buffered.

The sender code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE_SIZE 1024

typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MESSAGE_SIZE];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int msgid;
    int ret;
    struct msqid_ds msg_settings;
    long key;
        struct msgbuf msg;

    key = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    // print the message queue ID for reading via msgrcv
    printf( "Getting message queue with key = %ld\n", key);
    usleep( 1000000);

    msgid = msgget( (key_t)key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (msgid == -1) {
        perror("msgget failed with error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // read in current queue settings and then set the new
    // queue size.
    ret = msgctl(msgid, IPC_STAT, &msg_settings);
    msg_settings.msg_qbytes = 32767;
    msgctl( msgid, IPC_SET, &msg_settings);

    while( 1) {
        msg.mtype = 1; // we'll always leave this as 1
        memset( &(msg.mtext), 0, MESSAGE_SIZE);
        sprintf( msg.mtext, "hi");
        printf( "Sending data: %s\n", msg.mtext);
        ret = msgsnd( 1, &msg, MESSAGE_SIZE, IPC_NOWAIT);
        usleep( 500000);
        if( ret == -1) {
            perror( "msgsnd failed\n");
    }

    printf( "leaving...\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The receiver code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MESSAGE_SIZE 1024

typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long mtype;
    char mtext[MESSAGE_SIZE];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int msgtyp = 1;
    int ret;
    size_t msgsz;
    struct msgbuf mymsg;

    int msgid;
    msgid = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    printf( "Reading message queue with ID = %d\n", msgid);
    usleep( 1000000);
    while( 1) {
        msgsz = (size_t)MESSAGE_SIZE;
        ret = msgrcv( msgid, &mymsg, msgsz, msgtyp, IPC_NOWAIT);
        if( ret == ENOMSG) {
            usleep( 100000);
            continue;
        }

        if( ret == -1) {
            perror( "msgrcv failed");
        } else {
            printf( "Read data: %s", mymsg.mtext);
            }

        usleep( 100000);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the information: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/system

You just have to modify /etc/config/system and add `option buffersize 65535'.  Unfortunately, you can't go higher than 64k.

I made the change and it's definitely better, but not perfect.  I'm going to pare down my message size to try to accommodate more messages.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the original problem that I already solved:

```
On the receiver side, I always get a "Argument list too long" error.
I changed my code to just use a #define so that I'm (hopefully) not
making any errors when passing the size as an argument.  But when I
looked online for solutions to the E2BIG error, it says that the
size of the message is too large.  How can that be?
```

Ok, I failed to interpret this information correctly:

From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/apis/ipcmsgrc.htm:

```
[E2BIG]

Argument list too long.

The size in bytes of the message is greater than msgsz and the MSG_NOERROR flag is not set in the msgflg parameter.
```

I thought that MSG_NOERROR was optional.  Guess it isn't.  Problem #2 solved!  Just need to increase the number of messages in the queue somehow... and then I'll probably hit another snag.  :)

Answer (score 0):

See
 http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.uc.doc%2Fcucunx%2Fmqlinux.html

This describes the file sysctl.conf on linux, other O/Ss will have other mechanisms for the same thing.

Comment: I saw similar information before and tried to query the current values from OpenWRT, but it seems that it isn't configured in this manner.